# subreddits of user using PRAW or R

Tags: python, reddit, praw

How to get subreddits of a redditor from PRAW using python or RedditextractoR package in R.

Iam using these comments for sentiment analysis using reddit and need subbreddits a particular user is involved in.

I got comments posts and users using RedditextractoR package in R, But unable to get the information above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This answer is outdated and no longer working**

This worked for me:

```
import praw

user_name = "user_name_to_get"
user_agent = "subreddit analyzer"

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
user = r.get_redditor(user_name)

subs = set()

try:
    overview = user.get_overview()

    for item in overview:
        subs.add(item.subreddit.display_name)

except praw.errors.NotFound:
    print("Unable to find user")

print subs
```

Comment: I am new to python and struggling with this for several hours.It worked very well thank you very much.

Comment: do you know if using praw i can get a structured form of **subreddits** like in [redective](http://www.redective.com/) after you put any username in the search box

Comment: @anirudhreddy: Not that I know of. They are most likely just taking a count of the number of items for each subreddit, but that is just speculation.

Comment: 'Redditor' object has no attribute 'get_overview'

Comment: It has indeed. Unfortunately, this is the only stackoverflow question I got regarding this so I added that comment. I found the correct method too though. Posting it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fetched the subscribed subreddits of my own user-id using PRAW :

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='client-id',
                 client_secret="client-secret",
                 username='username',
                 password='password',
                 user_agent='agent')

subredditList = reddit.user.subreddits(limit=None)

for item in subredditList:
    print(item.display_name)
```